# Display dynamic message for updates/releases on a react redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react + redux app, I want to dynamically display some notifications/message  about new features/updates as header on our react + redux app. This message to be displayed would be entered as input type text in one of the component (Alert.js) . I capture the entered value as props in this component and pass this props to a child component(Header.js) which just displays the message captured. Then i simply call the child component Header in App.js passing the required props..  The issue i am facing is when the app reloads the component re-renders,  the props value becomes undefined and the message that i want to display in header goes away. How do retain a object's value in store until the entered input value is not changed.  I am new to react and redux. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an initial state for your reducer like so

```
const initialState = {
  message: "Welcome back"
}

const alertReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
    case "NEW_ACTION":
       return action.payload
    default:
       state
    }
}
```

This will give your app predefined data to be used in your components. To have dynamic data that you can preserve though, you're going to have to integrate a database like MongoDB or Firebase. That way you can pull data like "most recent alerts" and etc. Otherwise, there is no way for you to effectively persist data solely on React and Redux. Maybe local storage, but that data will only exist on your computer.

Comment: Thanks @yourfavoritedev for your quick response. That really helped. So you mean for dynamic data i will have to persist the entered input dispatching an action that just stores the entered input in database. And then on page load, dispatch another action that loads the data from database, using store.dispatch. Right?

Comment: @PingPong that is exactly what I mean.